# Substitute several words in all files in a folder based on a .txt file

Tags: macos, sed

If I have a .txt file with 4 columns that looks like this:

```
File          Genus           Species            Strain
KPLB.S001.gbk Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum S001
KPLB.S098.gbk Corynebacterium propinquum         S098
KPLB.S045.gbk Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum S045
KPLB.S690.gbk Dolosigranulum  pigrum             S690
```

And a folder that contains the 4 .gbk files listed in the first column. How could I replace each occurrence of the words "Genus" "Species or "Strain" inside the .gbk files with the corresponding names based on the table?

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Adding info on how the .gbk file looks inside:

```
LOCUS       NBOOEINI_1            375100 bp    DNA     linear       19-OCT-2020
DEFINITION  Genus species strain strain.
ACCESSION   
VERSION
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      Genus species
  ORGANISM  Genus species
            Unclassified.
COMMENT     Annotated using prokka 1.14.6 from
            https://github.com/tseemann/prokka.
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..375100
                     /organism="Genus species"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /strain="strain"
```

And this is the desired output

```
LOCUS       NBOOEINI_1            375100 bp    DNA     linear       19-OCT-2020
DEFINITION  Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum strain S001.
ACCESSION   
VERSION
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum
  ORGANISM  Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum
            Unclassified.
COMMENT     Annotated using prokka 1.14.6 from
            https://github.com/tseemann/prokka.
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..375100
                     /organism="Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /strain="S001"
```

The word strains is going to be more complicated because I need to change only the second occurrence in the DEFINITION line and also in the last line

Comment: Off of the top of my head, you can iterate over the files with `ls` or `find`, and for each, then use `cut` to grab the fields, then you can generate a one-liner that replaces all instances of the value in column 1 with the value in column two. If you post an example of a `.gbk` file, I should be able to help better.

Comment: Thanks ShawnMilo, I updated the question with info on the .gbk file

Comment: "then you can generate a one-liner that replaces all instances of the value in column 1 with the value in column two." that is the part that is more difficult for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you. This is what finally worked for me:

```
CONFIG='Get_Homologues/Renamed_Prokka/control.txt'
DIRECTORY='Get_Homologues/Renamed_Prokka/Genomes'

# These are the strings to be found in the files
SOURCE1='Genus'
SOURCE2='species'
SOURCE3='strain\.'
SOURCE4='\"strain\"'

# Skip the first line with the titles of the columns
DATA=`tail -n +2 $CONFIG`

while IFS= read -r LINE
do
   # Get the columns of the config file and store them into separate variables
   FILENAME=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'`
   REPLACE1=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}'`
   REPLACE2=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $3}'`
   REPLACE3=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $4}'`

   # Now replace each of the strings one by one, directly inside the file
   sed -i "" "s/$SOURCE1/$REPLACE1/g" $DIRECTORY/$FILENAME
   sed -i "" "s/$SOURCE2/$REPLACE2/g" $DIRECTORY/$FILENAME
   sed -i "" "s/$SOURCE3/$REPLACE3./g" $DIRECTORY/$FILENAME
   sed -i "" "s/$SOURCE4/\"$REPLACE3\"/g" $DIRECTORY/$FILENAME
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$DATA")
```

Comment: Does this work properly with `strain`? 

For example, '/strain="strain"' should be '/strain="S001"', not '/S001="S001".'

Comment: Yes. SOURCE3='strain\.' substitutes only the second strain in the sentence: "DEFINITION  Genus species strain strain." because search for the dot. And SOURCE4='\"strain\"' search for "strain". This way I get '/strain="S001"' without issues

Comment: Looks like  you learned some good stuff here. You're entitled to accept your own answer and gain reputation points for it (after ~48 hours), or you can accept someone else's answer and give them the rep. ALSO you can upvote any/all answers provided as a thank you to the writers for spending their time on your question. (It's also very nice that you have thanked all your contrubitors, that is rare! (-; ) Good luck to all!

Comment: Yes @shellter, I learnt a lot!! I usually check stackoverflow and piecing together some answers I usually figure out how to do stuff. But yesterday I finally gave up and created an account to ask my first question. So, thanks for the info on the reputation points, I was not really aware about how the site works. I was overwhelmed with some many questions so quickly, some of them came along as I was working on the first suggestions, so I wanted to thank everyone, even if I didn't use their code.

Comment: Be aware that giving others reputation points doesn't deduct from your total of reputation points. And I would encourage all the posters to this question to up-vote each others questions, as they all provided something of value for your problem. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I created the 4 files with the template content as listed above; I also created a file called `control.txt` that matches your `.txt` file above.

Using the following shell script as a wrapper around `sed` does what you're asking on my installation.

```
$ cat replace.sh 
#!/bin/bash
tail -n +2 control.txt | while read file genus species strain
do
  sed -i "/^DEFINITION/s/Genus/$genus/;/^DEFINITION/s/species/$species/;/^DEFINITION/s/strain\./${strain}./;/^SOURCE/s/Genus/$genus/;/^SOURCE/s/species/$species/;/  ORGANISM/s/Genus/$genus/;/^  ORGANISM/s/species/$species/;/\/organism=/s/Genus/$genus/;/\/organism=/s/species/$species/;/\/strain=/s/\"strain\"/\"${strain}\"/" $file
done
```

Comment: Thanks! It gave me an error because I was not giving a name for the new files doing sed -i ' '. Your code helped me figure out how to change "strain" only in the right places

Comment: sed: 1: "NAME OF FILE ...": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: That's odd ... do your actual file names contain spaces, or did you create the control text file on a windows machine?

Comment: I have a Mac. The files names are like: prokka_accolens_2617.spades.pilon.gbk

Comment: I haven't touched a Mac in quite some time, but I think the `sed` on MacOS requires an actual file-extension for the `-i` option.  Try `-i .bak` (read `man sed` to be sure.)

Comment: Apparently sed requires an output file, by doing sed -i "" writes over the input file as output. That is how I fixed

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the optimal solution but in my opinion is very readable and possible extensible:

```sh
CONFIG='config.txt'
DIRECTORY='/path/to/the/directory'

# These are the strings to be found in the files
SOURCE1='Genus'
SOURCE2='Species'
SOURCE3='Strain'

# Skip the first line with the titles of the columns
DATA=`tail -n +2 $CONFIG`

while IFS= read -r LINE
do
   # Get the columns of the config file and store them into separata variables
   FILENAME=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'`
   REPLACE1=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}'`
   REPLACE2=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $3}'`
   REPLACE3=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $4}'`

   # Now replace each of the strings one by one, directly inside the file
   sed -i "s/$SOURCE1/$REPLACE1/g" $DIRECTORY/$FILENAME
   sed -i "s/$SOURCE2/$REPLACE2/g" $DIRECTORY/$FILENAME
   sed -i "s/$SOURCE3/$REPLACE3/g" $DIRECTORY/$FILENAME
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$DATA")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mostly based my final code in your answer. I fixed the spelling on Species and Strain. I also modified to account for the different ways "strain" appears in the text. Also I have to edit sed -i to sed -i "" because gave me an error

Answer (score 1):

a bit verbose, but....
requires gawk with `IGNORECASE` and `gensub` support

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==NR {
   IGNORECASE=1
   if (FNR==1) {
       split($0,fldA)
       next
    }
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        arr[$1,fldA[i]]=$i
    fileA[$1]
    next
}
FILENAME in fileA {
    for(flds=2;flds in fldA;flds++)
       $0=gensub("([^/])" fldA[flds],"\\1" arr[FILENAME,fldA[flds]], "g")
}
1
```

```
$ cat KPLB.S001.gbk
OCUS       NBOOEINI_1            375100 bp    DNA     linear       19-OCT-2020
DEFINITION  Genus species strain strain.
ACCESSION
VERSION
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      Genus species
  ORGANISM  Genus species
            Unclassified.
COMMENT     Annotated using prokka 1.14.6 from
            https://github.com/tseemann/prokka.
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..375100
                     /organism="Genus species"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /strain="strain"
```

```
$ cat tst.txt
File          Genus           Species            Strain
KPLB.S001.gbk Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum S001
KPLB.S098.gbk Corynebacterium propinquum         S098
KPLB.S045.gbk Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum S045
KPLB.S690.gbk Dolosigranulum  pigrum             S690
```

running: `gawk -f tst.awk tst.txt KPLB.S001.gbk` results in:

```
OCUS       NBOOEINI_1            375100 bp    DNA     linear       19-OCT-2020
DEFINITION  Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum S001 S001.
ACCESSION
VERSION
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum
  ORGANISM  Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum
            Unclassified.
COMMENT     Annotated using prokka 1.14.6 from
            https://github.com/tseemann/prokka.
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..375100
                     /organism="Corynebacterium tuberculostearicum"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /strain="S001"
```

Adding a shell wrapper to deal with multiple files and other bells/whistles is left as an excersize for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This was tricky due to not wanting to replace *all* instances in the file (specifically with "strain," where it was being used as a label. Here's a Python script that works.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Update .gbk files from config file.
"""

import sys
from os.path import exists


# read config file for replacements
def get_replacements():
    repls = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as raw:
        for line in raw:
            # skip header row
            if line.startswith('File'):
                continue
            repls.append(line.strip().split())
    return repls


# replace last instance of 'old' in a line with 'new'
def replace_last(line, old, new):
    if not old in line:
        return line
    i = line.rindex(old)
    return line[:i] + new + line[i+len(old):]

def main():
    for filename, genus, species, strain in get_replacements():
        if not exists(filename):
            continue
        with open(filename, 'r') as raw:
            data = raw.read()
        update = []
        for line in data.split('\n'):
            line = replace_last(line, 'strain', strain)
            line = replace_last(line, 'Genus', genus)
            line = replace_last(line, 'species', species)
            update.append(line)
        with open(filename, 'w') as out:
            out.write('\n'.join(update))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Beware that this script overwrites the files, losing the originals. I did it this way because it seems like that's what you wanted to do. I added some comments to the Python to try to make it easier to understand, but I also tried to keep it short.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already found another useful piece of code and fixed the issue. But thanks for your answer too